# An internal error occurred during: "Initialize metrics". com/genuitec/eclipse/core/gsdc/GSDCController

Tags: myeclipse

When I run myeclipse 2015 stable cn 1.0, I got the following error message:

> An internal error occurred during: "Initialize metrics".com/genuitec/eclipse/core/gsdc/GSDCController

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just see this in the log or do you see an error dialog as well, and is this something you see on every workspace start?

If you look at the Error Log, can you find the stack trace corresponding to this and paste it here? Alternatively, do post at http://myeclipseide.com/forums for additional support.

**Update (Sep 22, 2017):** This issue has been fixed in version 2017 CI 8 of Webclipse / Angular IDE / Darkest Dark / MyEclipse. If you are using an earlier version, as pointed out below, the problem is caused by inability to write to your Eclipse installation. Re-installing into a location which does have write access would be the best approach, though you can run as Administrator on Windows too.

Comment: I have this problem with Eclipse, not myeclipse. I see this in the log and an error dialog as well. This is something I see on every worspace start.

This is stack trace from the log:
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Initialize metrics".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/genuitec/eclipse/core/gsdc/GSDCController
 at com.genuitec.eclipse.monitor.internal.MetricsManager.initialize(MetricsManager.java:153)
 at 

(part, I cannot insert it all at comment...)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall.

I had this problem with Eclipse, not MyEclipse, and it turned out that it was installed by another user in Program Files. Now I installed it at default location, under my user directory, and this error doesn't show anymore.

Also I manage to run this "bad" installation as administrator without such problems.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem but it happen in Eclipse.

I think this link may help you.

https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/initialize-metrics-has-encountered-a-problem/

General speaking, The problem is most likely caused due to the plugins not having `full write access` to your workspace or the Eclipse installation

so, you just do this: Run Eclipse as an administrator!

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem in MyEclipse.
Since last Month, I reinstall the system but the disk E. 
After install the new system, the disk E turned into disk D. 
So I modify the data myeclipse.ini and configuation/config.ini. I modify the E into D. 
Run MyEclipse got the following error message.
After I change back to the primary data and Move the MyEclipse to the new disk E. After it's OK.